# Woocommerce stripe checkout issue while submitting the checkout form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

When i try to submit the card details, i get this error

> " Please enter your card details to make a payment. Developers: Please
>   make sure that you are including jQuery and there are no JavaScript
>   errors on the page. "

Answer (score 0):

*This is typically caused by entering your Secret and Publishable Stripe keys in the incorrect order. Please go to the WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > Stripe tab and update both the Stripe Live Secret Key and Stripe Live Publishable Key. Make sure that your enter the proper corresponding keys from your Stripe account into each field.*

Taken from the official WooCommerce Stripe [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/).

Comment: Actually this error in test mode ? so what should i do ?

Comment: You've got the stripe keys entered incorrectly.  Double check them.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Also try and deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce and Stripe and see if the problem persists.

Comment: there is no console error.and i also checked with deactivating all of the plugins.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think it could be is that you have pasted the secret and publishable keys in the wrong fields like the official documentation states.  If it doesn't work with the bare minimum plugins and a default WordPress theme then I don't think there's any other cause to the issue.